# Left continuous random walk argument

Tags: martingales, random-walk

In the preceding example given, I am unclear

> 1) why $\alpha<1$ results in $\phi \left(\alpha \right)=1$
>   The only value on an exponential that results in 1 is 0.

The only value such that makes this true is a zero value on an exponent.

> 2) $\phi\left ( 0 \right )=1$ and $\phi'\left ( 0 \right )>0$

What? The derivative of a constant is positive?

This is frustrating. I would appreciate if anyone could clarify the above.

[image]

Comment: It does say " note that (i) f(0)=1", so that agrees with you.

Comment: No negative $\alpha$ may exists such that $\phi(\alpha)=1$ unless the RV $X_{i}$=0.

Also, "....so $\phi'(0)>0$"

Comment: And it does not say derivative of a constant, but derivative of a function at a point (that happens to be zero)